# What is a efficient way to order chunks of numpy array by one column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array of 6 columns:

```
x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2
```

I want to sort (xi,yi,zi) pair of columns by comparing y1 and y2.
If y2>y1, I want to swap such that in that row, the order is x2, y2, z2, x1, y1, z1.

What is the efficient way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your array `a` with shape `(n, 6)`. The following code will do the trick:

```
c = a[:, 4] > a[:, 1]
a[c, 0:3], a[c, 3:6] = a[c, 3:6], a[c, 0:3]
```

The boolean array `c` is a mask indicating where the condition `y2 > y1` is `True`. The second line applies the mask to swap the columns for the rows where this condition applies.